# Is it possible to show a graph of a class on another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, plot, graph, jframe

I am creating a program that solves functions and plots their graphs. At the moment, I only have two classes: a standard Java class (Graph) in which I have the code used to plot the graph and a `JFrame` (Main), used by the user to insert the variables.

I want to show on one of the frame's panels the graph, which has been coded in another class. Is this possible?

I have tried to add the class `Graph` on the `JFrame` in this way, but it doesn't work:

```
Public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame, Graph {
```

I also tried to launch the graph by using this code: Graph. Main (`new String[0]`), and it works, but when I close it, and I try to open it again, it doesn't respond.

```java
public class Graph extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Title");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("00");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Graph for the chosen function");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Points");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart, 700,500);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        //stage.setMaximized(true);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Alessandro! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read our [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"Is it possible to show a graph of a class on another JFrame?"* Yes.